# How send an email via a ovh-web-mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

i try to send automatically mails via my webmail, i did it with gmail and it functions as i want, but with my job mail, i can't send it;
there is my code:

```
def send_mail(peopler):
    mymail = "name.@watchelp-app.com"
    people = peopler
    sujet = "Pour favoriser l'autonomie des personnes autistes"
    mail_content = "Bonjour, \n blabla

    mail_content_final = mail_content

    password = "password"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = mymail
    msg['To'] = people
    msg['Subject'] =  sujet 
    message = mail_content_final
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('pro2.mail.ovh.net', 587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login(mymail, password)
    mailserver.sendmail(people, people, msg.as_string())
    mailserver.quit()
```

THe result gives me "smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')"

i'm sure about my logs and password, is it a problem with the port? or do i have to manage an access for my botmail?

THanks for yours answers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with the server : "ssl0.ovh.net", it's the one for the non-pro OHV webmail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).